# Access mailbox via Graph (MSAL.NET/Azure AD 2.0) from deamon service: administrator access should be limited to single mailboxes

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

When you access a mailbox of a specific user via a background service using MS Graph, the token will expire after 90 days since MSGraph (MSAL.NET/Azure AD 2.0) does not return a refresh token (see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal#adalnet-v2x-migration-to-msalnet-v2x)).

Using administrator consent should resolve this issue, but the only choice is to get access to ALL mailboxes of the organization. This is way too great a security risk for this task.

Does anybody know a middle ground for this?
Is there a way to get the refresh token when using user consent, or limit admin consent to 1 mailbox?

Is this an issue that Microsoft should resolve?

Comment: Which api are you requesting?

Comment: Carl, the question has been answered by Allen Wu. But to have complete documentation for other users: using Microsoft.Identity.Client; AcquireTokenSilent (https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph documentation has provided a method to accomplish this requirement.

Just use the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet to configure access control.

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."
```

See details from [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: Thank you, I preferred a solution where the admin does not need to perform specific tasks, but this really resolves the issue and answered my question.